# React objects rendering differently in two views

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two views/components in my React app that render books for a user.
In `ListBooks` it takes a set of 'books' on the users list and renders them left to right on the relevant shelves. This works ok.

The issue is on the `SearchBook` component. When a user enters a search string I want to display results left to right without going off the screen.

The book objects themselves are rendered by the `Book.js` component.

Like so:
xxxx
xxxx
xxxx

What I have currently is they are displaying one after the other on top of each other:

x
x
x

How do I display this correctly?

There's a fair amount of code so I've put the app itself in [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/richardcurteis/myreads-udacity/) as well as extracts in this post.

It will give you an error when you navigate to it but just click on the yellow tab in the sandbox's browser view and the app will work normally.
The SVGs on the green buttons don't seem to render either but they are just for navigation.

`ListBooks.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import './App.css'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import Book from './Book'

const shelves = [
  {
    key: 'currentlyReading',
    name: 'Currently Reading'
  },
  {
    key: 'wantToRead',
    name: 'Want To Read'
  },
  {
    key: 'read',
    name: 'Read'
  }
];

class ListBooks extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
       books: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
       onUpdateShelf: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    }

    render() {

        const { books, onUpdateShelf } = this.props

        function getBooksForShelf(shelfKey) {
          return books.filter(book => book.shelf === shelfKey);
        }

        return(
            <div className="app">
              <div className="list-books">
                <div className="list-books-title">
                  <h1>My Reads</h1>
                </div>
                <div className="list-books-content">
                  <div>
                    { shelves.map((shelf) => (
                      <div key={shelf.key} className="bookshelf">
                        <h2 className="bookshelf-title">{shelf.name}</h2>
                        { getBooksForShelf(shelf.key).length === 0 ? (
                          <div>
                            <h4>No books in this shelf</h4>
                          </div>
                        ) : (
                          <div className="bookshelf-books">
                            <ol className="books-grid">
                              <li>
                                { getBooksForShelf(shelf.key).map((book) => (
                                 <Book key={book.id}
                                     book={book}
                                     updateShelf={onUpdateShelf}/>
                                  ))}
                              </li>
                            </ol>
                          </div> 
                        )}
                      </div>
                    )) }
                  </div>
                </div>
                  <Link
                      to='/search'
                      className="open-search">
                  </Link>
              </div>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ListBooks
```

`SearchBooks.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import * as BooksAPI from './utils/BooksAPI'
import Book from './Book';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

export default class SearchBooks extends Component {

    state = {
        query: '',
        results: []
    }

    static propTypes = {
      onUpdateShelf: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    }

    updateQuery(query) {
        if(query.length > 0 ) {
          this.setState(() => ({
            results: [],
            query: query
        }))
          this.bookSearch(query)
        }
        else {
          this.clearQuery()
        }
    }

    clearQuery = () => {
      this.setState({
        query: '',
        results: []
      })
    }

    bookSearch(e) {
      if (e.length > 0)
        BooksAPI.search(e)
        .then(searchResults => this.setState(currentState => ({
          results: this.updateExistingShelves(searchResults)
        })));
     }

     updateExistingShelves(searchResults) {
       if(searchResults.error !== "empty query") {
        const myBooks = this.props.books
        const addToState = searchResults.filter((result) => myBooks.find(b => {
          if(b.id === result.id) {
            result.shelf = b.shelf
            return result
          }
        }))
        myBooks.concat(addToState)
        return searchResults
       }
     }

    render() {

        const { query, results } = this.state
        const { onUpdateShelf } = this.props

        return(
            <div className="search-books">
                <div className="search-books-bar">
                  <button
                    className="close-search"
                    onClick={ this.clearQuery }>
                  </button>
                  <div className="search-books-input-wrapper">
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Search by title, author or subject"
                        value={query}
                        onChange={(event) => this.updateQuery(event.target.value)}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="search-books-results">
                  <ol className="books-grid">
                    <li>
                      { results ? (
                        results.map((book) => (
                          <Book
                            key={book.id}
                            book={book}
                            updateShelf={onUpdateShelf} 
                             />
                          ))
                        ) : (
                          <h4>No results for, "{query}"</h4>
                        )}
                    </li>
                  </ol>
                  <Link
                    to='/'
                    className="return-home">
                  </Link>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

`Book.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'


class Book extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
        book: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        updateShelf: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    }    

    render() {

        const { book, updateShelf } = this.props

        return(
            <div key={book.id} className="book">
                <div className="book-top">
                    <div className="book-cover" style={{ width: 128, height: 193,
                    backgroundImage: (book.imageLinks) ? 
                        `url(${book.imageLinks.thumbnail})`
                        : `url(${'icons/no_image_available'})` }}></div>
                        <div className="book-shelf-changer"> 
                            <select value={book.shelf ? book.shelf : 'none'} onChange={(e) => updateShelf(book, e.target.value)}>
                                <option disabled >Move to...</option>
                                <option value="currentlyReading" >Currently Reading</option>
                                <option value="wantToRead" >Want to Read</option>
                                <option value="read" >Read</option>
                                <option value="none" >None</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div className="book-title">{book.title}</div>
                <div className="book-authors">{book.authors}</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Book
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is actually a CSS issue. You have a class `list-books-content` that is applied to the Currently Reading section that uses a flex box to style the books inline. That class isn't applied to the search books. If you want a quick fix you can just add `display: inline-block` to the `.book` class.

Comment: What would be a better fix? At the moment the book objects are ordered right but really messy

Answer (score 0):

After looking into your app.css file. You can use style "list-books-content" for  tag in search book file. it will list all the books properly.

Comment: I tried that as well as trying adding a `div` with class `list-books-content` in `Book.js`. The latter only put them on one line

Comment: i changed it to books-grid it is being displayed in wrapping format right. one after another. add some padding for book then they wont be wrappend